# How to mock an mutation argument in Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, graphene-python

I have a mutation that has a decorator that checks the permissions (scopes) from the user token before s/he goes inside it. The decorator gets the input parameter from the mutate method and extracts the token and verify if the user has one of the allowed scopes.

The unit tests don't succeed if I don't remove or mock the requires_scope part from the code. The problem is that I don't know exactly what I have to mock to succeed in the unit tests. Should I mock the input itself? The token? The return of the requires_scopes decorator?

mutations.py

```
class MyMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    success = graphene.Boolean()

    class Arguments:
        input = graphene.Argument(IdInput, required=True)

    @classmethod
    @requires_scopes(['app:first_test_permission', 'app:second_test_permission'])
    def mutate(cls, root, info, input):
        pass
```

decorators.py

```
def get_access_token_from_header(request):
    """
    Obtains the Access Token from the Authorization Header
    """
    header = request.context.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
    header = header.split()
    token = header[1]

    return token


def requires_scopes(scopes: list):
    """
    Determines if the required scope is present in the Access Token
    Args:
        scopes (list): The scopes required to access the resource
    """

    def require_scopes(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            token = get_access_token_from_header(args[2])
            decoded = jwt.decode(token, verify=False)

            if decoded.get("scope"):
                token_scopes = set(decoded["scope"].split())
                required_scopes = set(scopes)
                if required_scopes.intersection(token_scopes):
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)

            raise Exception({'message': 'You don\'t have access to this resource'})

        return decorated

    return require_scopes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mocked the `get_access_token_from_header` function:

```
MY_TOKEN = 'mytoken'

@patch('app.decorators.get_access_token_from_header', return_value=MY_TOKEN)
def test_my_mutation_successfully(self, get_access_token_from_header_mocker):
    pass
```